# Using an array as a map JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to create a program that will give the **optimal location to place a hospital**, using the formula d = ((x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)<sup>0.5</sup>. The optimal locations are located in the green circles with the following coordinates (11,8), (9,9),(9,19) and (13,13).

[image: image of maps]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class hospitalBuilderProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        byte[][][] maps = {
            {{2, 2}, {2, 8}, {5, 15}, {19, 1}, {17, 17}},
            {{1, 1}, {7, 19}, {13, 19}, {19, 7}, {19, 13}},
            {{0, 19}, {2, 19}, {4, 19}, {6, 19}, {18, 19}},
            {{7, 19}, {13, 19}, {19, 19}, {19, 13}, {19, 7}}
        };

        for (int row = 1; row <= 19; row++) {
            for (int col = 1; col <= 19; col++) {
                int d1 = (((x1 - row) ^ 2 + (y1 - col) ^ 2));
                int d2 = ((x2 - row) ^ 2 + (y2 - col) ^ 2);
                int d3 = ((x3 - row) ^ 2 + (y3 - col) ^ 2);
                int d4 = ((x4 - row) ^ 2 + (y4 - col) ^ 2);
                int d5 = ((x5 - row) ^ 2 + (y5 - col) ^ 2);

                if (d1 == d2 == d3 == d4 == d5)
                    return (row, col);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to fix my code accordingly but I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: i guess you want `maps[row][col][0]` and `maps[row][col][1]` instead of working the index of the array as of `(x1-row)^2 + (y1-col)`. Also there isn´t any variable `x1` or `y1` defined anywhere

Comment: why is your row and column starting from `1` instead of `0` Where are your `x1..x5` and`y1..y5`

Comment: Where are x.. and y... defined?

Comment: BtW: Pay attention to the java naming convention. Classnames yout start with uppercase values.

Comment: @KevinEsche No I want to use arrays for this program

Comment: What are you trying to do in this code `(((x1 - row) ^ 2 + (y1 - col) ^ 2)); if you are thinking this will square the difference that might be a problem

Answer (score 0):

This solution elaborate the barycenter of the different location:

```
public static void locateHospital() {
   final byte[][][] maps = {
      {{2,  2}, { 2,  8}, { 5, 15}, {19,  1}, {17, 17}},
      {{1,  1}, { 7, 19}, {13, 19}, {19,  7}, {19, 13}},
      {{0, 19}, { 2, 19}, { 4, 19}, { 6, 19}, {18, 19}},
      {{7, 19}, {13, 19}, {19, 19}, {19, 13}, {19,  7}}
   };
   for( final byte[][] map : maps ) {
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0;
      for( final byte[] coords : map ) {
         x += coords[0];
         y += coords[1];
      }
      x /= 5;
      y /= 5;
      System.out.printf( "Hospital should be placed in {%d, %d}\n", x, y );
   }
}
```

The output:

```
Hospital should be placed in {9, 8}
Hospital should be placed in {11, 11}
Hospital should be placed in {6, 19}
Hospital should be placed in {15, 15}
```

It's not your problem nor your solution but it can help... ;-)

To be more accurate, each location described by the data should give its population to weight the barycenter.